# text mining library or lingual library?

Tags: text, data-mining, text-mining

i have a bunch of data harvested from a forum I own, and would like to do some text mining or use some linguistic library to extract useful information.

any text mining, data mining library in any language will do.

Thank you.

Comment: What would you like to mine? Sometimes it is harder to define the problem, than the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you have [a look at R](http://www.r-project.org/).  It has an extensive number of text mining packages: [have a look at the Natural Language Processing view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html).  In particular, look at the `tm` package.  Here are some relevant links:

- Paper about the package in the Journal of Statistical Computing: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v25/i05/paper.  The paper includes a nice example of an analysis of the R-devel
  mailing list (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/) newsgroup postings from 2006.
- Package homepage: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html
- Look at the introductory vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf

Another example of useful package for this is [Gary King's readme package](http://gking.harvard.edu/readme/).

Answer (score 2):

You may like to have a look at the Python [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (Natural Language ToolKit): it's specifically designed for this kind of thing.

There is also a [great book](http://www.nltk.org/book) you can but to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

[Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) is a java library designed for text mining. Once you have preprocessed the text data, a general data mining tool like [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) would also suffice your task.

If you have access to SPSS or SAS, their products should be more easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try GATE, it has GUI and of course you can use java api for more power:
http://gate.ac.uk/family/developer.html

You can also use Weka for processing text and doing text mining, have a look at these useful lectures:
http://sentimentmining.net/weka/

Comment: Some of the weka lectures seem to have broken download links.

Answer (score 0):

stanford core-nlp is good for English text, and has things like Named Entity Recognition. Take a look at: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

GATE, which Ehsan already recommended, is also good, but it can be a bit complicated if you need to write your own components. For large-scale stuff it's great though.

UIMA is similar to GATE, but not as easy to use because it doesn't feature an extensive GUI like GATE. (http://uima.apache.org)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following Python libraries:

1. `nltk`
2. `keras`
3. `tensorflow`

*Note: Before any text analysis you should clean the data based on your requirement*